# Arduino: for loops in micros()

Tags: c++, arduino

I have effectively replicated the "no delay blink" example on my Arduino Mega2560 to send pulses to a stepper motor driver. I included a `for` loop to increment the number of "pulses" given to achieve a single rotation (800 pulses), then delay for a moment and repeat.

I find that the motor is only rotating a fraction of a revolution. It would seem that the `micros()` running faster than the `for` loop resulting in missed pulses. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out why this may be, and how to work around it.

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int Pul_OUT = 9;
unsigned long previousMicros = 0;
unsigned long Pul_Interval = 100;
int setPosition = 800;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Pul_OUT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Pul_OUT, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  no_delay_Position();
  delay(100);
}

int no_delay_Position()
{
  for (int i = setPosition; i >= 0 ; i--)
  { 
    unsigned long currentMicros = micros();
    if (currentMicros - previousMicros > Pul_Interval) 
    {
      previousMicros = currentMicros;
      PulState = !PulState;
      digitalWrite(Pul_OUT, PulState);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop in `no_delay_Position()` will decrement `i` whether a pulse is sent or not (because that is determined by `Pul_interval`), so `i` will reach 0 before `i` pulses are sent.

Also, `no_delay_Position()` will not return until its `for` loop is done, and during that time, `loop()` is blocked.

Also, your `Pul_Interval` is only 100µs which is 0.1ms. You may want to replace `micros()` with `millis()` and see what happens.

BTW 100ms is still fairly quick for pulsing a stepper motor, you could try a larger `Pul_Interval` if the above is still too fast. There's nothing wrong with testing with a step every second or so, just to see if the algorithm works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`delay()` is measured in milliseconds, microseconds are just a fraction of this.

From the `micros()` [reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/micros/):

> There are 1,000 microseconds in a millisecond and 1,000,000
> microseconds in a second.

Adding the `delay(100)` in your main loop will also stop the arduino from doing [most things](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/). If for some reason you need to use `millis()` in the outer loop and `micros()` in the set position loop you could do something like this

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int Pul_OUT = 9;
unsigned long previousMicros = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
int Pul_Interval = 100;
int Main_Interval = 100;
int setPosition = 800;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Pul_OUT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Pul_OUT, LOW);
}


void loop()
{
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis > Main_Interval) 
    {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      no_delay_Position();
    } 
}

void no_delay_Position()
{
  for(int i = setPosition; i >= 0 ; i--)
  { 
    unsigned long currentMicros = micros();
    if (currentMicros - previousMicros > Pul_Interval) 
    {
      previousMicros = currentMicros;
      PulState = !PulState;
      digitalWrite(Pul_OUT, PulState);
    }
  }
}
```

The call to `no_delay_Position()` looks to be set to return an `int` did you mean to be able to pass in an integer to set the position?

```
void loop()
{
  no_delay_Position(500);
}


void no_delay_Position(int setP)
{
  setPosition = setP;
  for(int i = setPosition; i >= 0 ; i--)
  { 
     //rest of your code
  }
}
```